# Why do two adjacent arrays return undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The following case returns `undefined` in Chrome devtools.

`['test1', 'test2']['test3', 'test4']`.

I believe this may be because of [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631105/why-does-3-1-2-return-undefined-in-javascript), but this case I'm finding hard to understand when running in the Chrome devtools.

The following (and other permutations of `;` in different locations) returns the last item, `['test3', 'test4']`:

`;['test', 'test2'];['test3', 'test4'];`

I believe this case is different from the [marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions) because the usage of the comma doesn't cause any of the individual items to be returned (it makes sense that `'test3','test4'` would return `'test4'`, but in this instance the commas are within the context of arrays).

Comment: To expand on the duplicate: ASI never inserts a semicolon without a line break. Instead, the comma operator is making the expression equivalent to `['test1', 'test2']['test4']`. The comma operator is a mistake.

Comment: Are you sure? The expression returns `['test3', 'test4']` - it doesn't omit `'test3'`. The comma operator doesn't seem like it would be a mistake or illegal within the context of an array, unless the brackets are being interpreted as something else.

Comment: The brackets are indeed being interpreted as something else: bracketed property access. Consider `var a = ['test1', 'test2'];`. `a[0]` is `'test1'`. `a[1]` is `'test2'`. `a[2]` is `undefined`. `a['test4']` is `undefined`. `a['test3', 'test4']` is `undefined`. `['test1', 'test2']['test3', 'test4']` is `undefined`.

Comment: `;['test', 'test2'];['test3', 'test4'];` is completely different (two statements); see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618270/using-a-blocks-return-value-in-javascript